# Getting Data From Database using Id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have **one table** which contains the list of **Years having coulmns YearId and Years**
 and **Second table** which contains the list of car companies having colum **MakeId, MakeName, and YearId.**
I am not getting what sql query i have to write if i want that when i am selecting YearId =1 then i only get MakeName having **YearId=1** but when i am selecting YearId=2 ,i can get the MakeName of both Years of Id 1 and 2 and so on for 3,4,5...

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  But your question suggests `where yearId <= 2`.

Comment: How can i add sql table into this??

Comment: Use a filter. Where yearid <= input

Comment: Google SQL join for adding a table.

Comment: I want if I selected year 2010 then i can get list of all company till Year 2010 but if i selected Year 2018 then i can get list of all cars from till 2018 not for only in 2018

Comment: Yes Problem Solved...Thank You EveryOne For your rplies....Gordon Linoff  LJ01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `<=` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mtytable
WHERE  YearId <= 2 -- Or any other year you're passing
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this query  replace first_table by your table name and second_table by your second table

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    first_table a
LEFT JOIN second_table AS b
ON
    a.yearid = b.yearid
WHERE
    a.yearid > 2
```